# Copy same specific parts of a file to another file

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing

How can I copy same specific parts of a file to another file? In the first file, I have:

```
user01: Id name nationality
user02: Id name nationality
.
.
.
```

I want to copy each piece of information to a specific file (one file for Id and another for name and another one for nationality).

Comment: Use `cat` infront i.e. `cat file1.txt > file2.txt`

Comment: Please formulate your question in a way so that it's clear what you want. It is often very helpful to amend the question with clear data samples, so that we can **unambiguously** see what you have in the various files and how to compose that data to obtain what you expect as result. Keep the data samples as terse as possible, but as expressive as necessary.

Comment: Do you want a separate file for each user? So, 3 files per user? Or do you want all ids in one file, all names in another etc? Please [edit] your question and show us your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
sed 'h;s/\(: *[^ ]*\)\(.*\)/\1/pw id
     g;s//:\2/;h;s//\1/pw name
     g;s//:\2/w nationality' <infile
```

... which will write all output to stdout, but only the relevant stuff to each file. Running that on your example data, and I get:

```
user01: Id
user01: name
user01: nationality
user02: Id
user02: name
user02: nationality
```

... printed to stdout, and ...

```
head id name nationality

==> id <==
user01: Id
user02: Id
==> name <==
user01: name
user02: name
==> nationality <==
user01: nationality
user02: nationality
```

Answer (score 2):

`cp` is usually used for copying.

```
cp file1.txt file2.txt
```

To append to an existing file, use

```
cat file1.txt >> file2.txt
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP completely changed their question.

Answer (score 2):

The command for that is `cp`:

```
cp file1.txt file2.txt
```

If you want to append to another existing file you can use:

```
cat file1.txt >> file2.txt
```

Comment: thank you it's good but if i want to copy a specific part or lines how i do

Comment: @AomineDaiki can you edit your question to explain more about 'specific part' ? line with a word ? without whitespace ? line 10 and above ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP completely changed their question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the cut command.
For example to extract the first column and save in a file you can type:

```
cut -f1 -d" " sample > file1.txt
```

the `-f1` parameter specify which column do you want use, in this case the first one.

the `-d" "` is the separator

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! I'm afraid this isn't an answer. Please [edit] your answer and show how cut can be used for what the OP requests. You're just giving the manual, not the needed command. You should also show how the output will be redirected to different files.